# CloudConfigurationManager doesn't overwrite settings from an external file

Tags: c#, azure, f#, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

I've just found an obscure, yet deeply frustrating, bug with `CloudConfigurationManager`. I'm looking for workarounds, and also (as a side note) tips about the best forum in which to report the bug. I'm guessing it will be a relatively quick fix.

I've got an Azure app service that connects to DocumentDb with config settings called `DocumentDB.Endpoint` and `DocumentDB.Key`. These are picked up in F# with

```
let endpoint = config.ReadConfigSetting<string>("DocumentDB.Endpoint")
let key = config.ReadConfigSetting<string>("DocumentDB.Key")
```

The `ReadConfigSetting` method is a convenience method that performs the relevant type conversions and default assignments. Under the covers it uses `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`.  For our purposes, think of the call as

```
let endpoint = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DocumentDB.Endpoint")
let key = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DocumentDB.Key")
```

I have a webjob that performs cron jobs on my document DB collections. `CloudConfigurationManager` picks up the setting from the app service settings first, and if the key is not found in the app service settings, it will look at my webjob's `app.config`.

In my QA environment, my webjob is picking the **correct endpoint**, but the **wrong key**. This is because `DocumentDb.Endpoint` is listed directly in my `app.config` file, but `DocumentDb.Key` is in a separate file that is `.gitignore`d. I don't want sensitive keys in the Git repo, even though it is private, and the credentials are only listed in app.config and my external file as a convenience that lets me run the job locally with a debugger.

So here is my setup:

**App.config**

```
<appSettings file="keys.config">
  <add key="agentUserName" value="<Everyone can read this>" />
  <add key="apiHost" value="<and this>" />
  <add key="DocumentDB.Endpoint" value="<points to my remote develpment copy of DocumentDB -- looking forward to when I can get a local repo>" />
</appSettings>
```

**keys.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DocumentDB.Key" value="<This is private, so it's in this gitignored file>" />
  <add key="agentPassword" value="<I'm not telling you>" />
  <add key="TestUserPassword" value="<I'd be an idiot to post this value in a SO question>" />
</appSettings>
```

You can see what's happening.

**Expected behaviour of CloudConfigurationManager when looking up the value of DocumentDB.Key**

1. Look at the underlying app serice settings for a value of DocumentDB.Key
2. If it exists, use that.
3. Otherwise, look in `App.config`.
4. If it's not there, look in `keys.config`.

**Actual behaviour of CloudConfigurationManager**

1. Is there a value in `keys.config`?
2. If so, use that value.
3. Then look at the app service settings
4. Then `App.config`.

The best workaround I have right now is to comment out the value in `keys.config` when I publish the web job, but that's clunky. Are there any better ways of doing this?

And where is the best place to log this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into Azure Key Vault? Here is an intro to Azure Key Vault: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/

If you store DocumentDB secrets in the Azure Key Vault, you can grant the access to the secrets to the application level. Here is another article that shows how to do it inside a web application: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/

Hope that helps.

Thanks.

Lengning